# Как задействовать автоматическое распараллеливание в Visual Studio, используя Intel Compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, многопоточность, распараллеливание, intel

Я знаю, что это делается с помощью ключа `/Qparallel`, однако "распараллеливаться" не хочет.  Даже пробовал приписывать `#pragma parallel` перед циклом((.
Вот код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

long long n = 110000000;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian")
    long double Z = 0;
    clock_t start = clock();
//#pragma parallel
    for (long long i = 2; i < N; ++i)
        Z += pow(-1, i) / (pow(i, 4.0 / 3) - sqrt(i));
    clock_t end = clock();
    std::cout << "Время = " << (end - start) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Результат = " << Z << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Обычная последовательная программа выполняется где-то в промежутке от 25 до 32 секунд. При ключе `/Qparallel` время вычислений остаётся таким же. Нагрузок на логические процессоры нет. Когда как, используя OpenMP, всё в порядке.
Пробовал включить также вывод отчёта `(/Qpar-report3)`. Всё также ничего.

Comment: Брр... Intel Compiler - это компилятор от Intel, Visual Studio - от Microsoft... Как довезти мебель на грузовике, используя мотоцикл? :) Или я чего-то не понял?

Comment: @Harry, intel использует VS как IDE

Comment: Что значит "ничего не хочет делать"? Ну а вообще не стоит особо полагаться на автоматическое распараллеливание. @Harry [Компиляторы Intel прекрасно интегрируются в VS](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-compilers-integration-support-for-microsoft-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Тогда мой вопрос снят. Не сталкивался. Если бы речь шла, почему VC++ не параллелизует, ну, тут можно было бы поговорить, а с Intel'ами - увы, не работал.

Comment: Вот тут https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/articles/automatic-parallelization-with-intel-compilers написано, что `Вывод отчета разрешается с помощью опции -par-report3 (Linux) или -Qpar-report3 (Windows)`

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то речь идёт о `OMP`, оно есть и в `VS` и в `gcc`, это внешняя библиотека, ее просто поддерживают компиляторы понимая их `ключи в формате pragma`. Но можно вместо ключей использовать `C/C++` код. Справочную информацию разумно искать по тегу `OMP`, например: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP , https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/openmp-in-visual-cpp?view=vs-2017 , https://habr.com/ru/company/intel/blog/85273/

Comment: То что вы пытаетесь сделать, это предложить компилятору векторизовать участки кода на его усмотрение с помощью `OMP`, эквивалентная строчка для `gcc`: `g++ -O3 -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=7`. Так вот по практике, начинает работать только при включенной оптимизации `-O2/3` и желательно выключенном дебаге `-g`. С учётом что библиотека одна и та же, полагаю что с ключами проблемы похожие.

Comment: И попробуйте использовать при векторизации `#pragma omp simd` она больше подходит к задаче.

Comment: но лучше сразу начинать с TBB, это всё же таки C++, а не прагмы

Comment: В таком случае, лучше вот этот обзор https://habr.com/ru/company/intel/blog/127491/ :) для мотивированного выбора

Comment: А что содержится в этом отчете? Вы уверены, что выполняете требования для автоматического распараллеливания? Например количество итераций цикла тут не задается константным выражением. @NewView Вы путаете параллелизм и векторизацию. в gcc OMP включается посредством `-fopenmp`, `-g` на оптимизацию никак не влияет. А компилятор Intel поддерживает авто распараллеливание без OMP.